# Angular how to save a whole page or component data to be used later

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

i have an angular 6 app that has different components(screens) that use @angular/material  horizontal stepper and each step has complex forms(template driven forms and formgroups) and i want to save the whole steps in draft(may be in localStorage or mongodb) if the process is not finished or if a user want to save in order to continue later, but all components structure are different because they have different formgroups and class member variables so what i'm asking is there any solution to save the whole stepper or whole angular component with data so when a user want to use will continue the process without losing his/her data?

**NOTE**: all components has different variables that changes during forms filling and some are used to hide some part of the app/formControls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser web storage, most latest browsers now support this feature https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp if your are moving out of the page you can always check on this storage but with session storage you have to be aware that for every new tab you lose the data you saved on session storage if you need the data to be accessible on the whole browser even by other tabs local storage would be appropriate other else you may also use cookies as well to maintain the data and restore the user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to save customer data in the server cache or db, you can maintain the status if it isDraft or isSave or isSubmitted, so you can get the details if customer has save or submitted the data.